# Why is Geth ignoring --nodiscover?

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, node-discovery, clique

I'm firing up a test network like so:

`geth --networkid=43766 --datadir ~/.ethereum/authchaintestnet/ --unlock b40474571297fd05ac82fd2994f45c977f3ca77a --password ~/.ethereum/authchaintestnet/passwordfile --mine --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcapi eth,net,web3,personal --verbosity=4 --nodiscover`

... but Geth keeps trying to connect to a bunch of peers that have nothing to do with my network. Why is Geth ignoring the `nodiscover` flag?

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same issue. It appears that `--nodiscover` is just disabling your node from running node-discovering algorithm to find peers to connect, but it doesn't prevent others from discovering and attempting to connect to your node. If you'd like to limit the inbound connection attempts, you could specify `--netrestrict`. 
e.g. `--netrestrict="127.0.0.1/8"`

Answer (score 1):

You could give your node a nodekey (see `--nodekey`) and set it as bootnode (see `--bootnodes`). See also the `bootnode` executable for how to easily create a nodekey and the associated enode URL.

With this, you remove it completely from the public Ethereum network. As it is, your `geth` connects to the public Ethereum bootnodes. That's how it gets discovered by others.